# How to decrypt string froom textbuffer.get_text

Tags: python, string, gtk

i encode a char 'a' by pyDes and I want to decode it

```
   text = self.textbuffer.get_text(start, end)
   print text
   //',\xcc\x08\xe5\xa1\xa1fc'
   x = "{}".format(text)
   print x
   //',\xcc\x08\xe5\xa1\xa1fc'
but i need 
   //,塡fc
```

when i do

```
cipher_text = ',\xcc\x08\xe5\xa1\xa1fc'
print cipher_text
//,塡fc
```

why

```
    text = self.textbuffer.get_text(start, end)
didn't return me a good string ?
```

your solution's didn't work here, but i make a progress:

```
text = self.textbuffer.get_text(start, end)
a = text.decode('unicode-escape')
g = a.encode('utf-16be')
```

it's almost good but when i do

```
print g
//',���fc'
print "%r"%g
//"\x00'\x00,\x00\xcc\x00\x08\x00\xe5\x00\xa1\x00\xa1\x00f\x00c\x00'"
```

now i've got problem with how to delete all \x00 here

```
newstr = g.replace("\x00", "")
newstr2 = newstr.replace("'", "")
```

newstr2 it's a bad solution it work's for small strings only

Comment: Something is seriously amiss. `',\xcc\x08\xe5\xa1\xa1fc'` is not a valid UTF-8 string. A UTF-8 representation of `,塡fc` would be ',\xe5\xa1\xa1fc'. But you're not getting either of those strings from the text buffer, you're getting the *quoted* version of the former. In other words, the string you're getting would be input to Python as `"',\\xcc\\x08\\xe5\\xa1\\xa1fc'"`. How that buffer ends up in your text buffer (and how it is ever shown by GTK as anything except `',\xcc\x08\xe5\xa1\xa1fc'`) is what you should investigate.

Comment: Another question is how and why do you expect encrypting `a` to result in `,塡fc`. This is not how encryption works: encryption normally transforms bytes into bytes. To encrypt unicode data, you first convert it to bytes, then you encrypt them. But those encrypted bytes cannot be treated as representation of unicode data anymore, they look like garbage to a UTF-8 (or other) decoder, which will at best produce [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) when fed them.

Comment: I know i use pyDes to encrypt 'a', and this is result',\xcc\x08\xe5\xa1\xa1fc' when I have my encrypt version in variable there is no problem to decrypt it, but when i use textbuffer.get_text to get my encrypt version it's return me a good string but in bad format and i can't decrypt it

Comment: How do you insert `',\xcc\x08\xe5\xa1\xa1fc'` into the textbuffer?

Comment: self.textbuffer.set_text("%r" % k.encrypt(text)

Comment: You are putting a quoted string into the textbuffer, and are getting the quoted string back. You need to *unquote* it - I've now added an answer that explains how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are getting from the textbuffer is a *quoted* string, which is because you quoted it before putting it there. If you quote the string before putting it into the textbuffer:

```
self.textbuffer.set_text("%r" % k.encrypt(text))
```

then you need to unquote it after retrieving it:

```
import ast
text = ast.literal_eval(self.textbuffer.get_text(start, end))
```

This will get you the original string you put in.

This design will not work if the user enters an arbitrary string in the text view, which can easily cause an exception, or cause `text` to be assigned an object of incorrect type, such as a number, or a list. To avoid that, you can get rid of the quotes when putting the text in the buffer, and use the `codecs` module for escaping in both directions:

```
import codecs
self.text.buffer.set_text(codecs.encode(text, 'string-escape'))
...
text = codecs.decode(self.text.buffer.get_text(start, end), 'string-escape')
```

Answer (score 1):

you should better use the new string formatting system:

```
>>> cipher_text = ',\xcc\x08\xe5\xa1\xa1fc'
>>> print cipher_text
,塡fc
>>> print "%r" % cipher_text
',\xcc\x08\xe5\xa1\xa1fc'
>>> print "{}".format(cipher_text)
,塡fc
>>> p = "%r" % cipher_text
>>> print p
',\xcc\x08\xe5\xa1\xa1fc'
>>> p = "{}".format(cipher_text)
>>> print p
,塡fc
```

it looks like the old way to format strings has serious unicode vs ascii issues (which is something I'm discovering as I'm trying this out), whereas the new format system works like a charm. Furthermore, it's python3 ready!

- *edit after more details has been added to the question:*

afaict, gtk has no issues working with unicode strings. You should get a unicode string out of a TextBuffer.get_text(). So to be sure of what I'm assuming, you should first do:

```
print type(text)
```

to see if a TextBuffer returns a `str()` or a `unicode()` object.

Then, you may try

```
text = unicode(self.textbuffer.get_text(start, end)
```

or

```
text = self.textbuffer.get_text(start, end).encode('utf-8')
```

or even

```
text = '{}'.format(self.textbuffer.get_text(start_end))
```

things can often get tricky when converting between utf-8 and ascii in python. There's a good manual on the topic, and things are a lot less painful using python3, which uses unicode per default. There's a big document on the topic in the python2 reference: [unicode howto](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html).

Comment: ok but 
       text = self.textbuffer.get_text(start, end)
       print text
       //',\xcc\x08\xe5\xa1\xa1fc'
       x = "{}".format(text)
       print x
       //',\xcc\x08\xe5\xa1\xa1fc'
    but i need 
       //,塡fc

Comment: are you talking about a [gtk.TextBuffer](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktextbuffer.html) object? You know that we can't read your mind and guess what is the mysterious "textbuffer" you're talking about only because you mention once in your question... If that's the one I'm thinking about, you should at least add the `gtk` tag to your question

Comment: sorry, try to repair my mistake

Comment: "Old" (C-style) formatting is perfectly usable in both Python 2 and 3 and is not going away. In this case, the `%r` format string is doing the `repr`, while `%s` would avoid it. (Of course, a sole `%s` doesn't make much sense on a single string.)

Comment: hum... I understood that the new preferred way of doing string formatting is using the new way, and that's what I meant. Anyway whether he uses `%s` or `%r` the utf-8 conversion problem stays the same, with `%s` it ends up with a encode/decode nightmare.

Comment: The tricky (and not exactly obvious) part is that there is no UTF-8 conversion problem because there is no UTF-8 conversion involved. The OP encrypts bytes a byte sequence A, producing a new byte sequence B. He then puts an *escaped* (i.e. pure-ASCII) version of B into a text buffer. What he wants to get out of the text buffer is the byte sequence B. No UTF-8 or Unicode is involved anywhere, except in the mojibake he gets when printing B to stdout. To get B out of the quoted content of the text buffer, he doesn't need any Unicode decoding, he needs the reverse of `repr`, which is `eval`.